# Asp.net Menu, how to customize?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, menu

I'm making a web application and I would like a "cute" jquery based menu for it. My asp.net Menu works fine but he is so ugly.. 
I dream of something like [this](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/386_navigation/top-nav-demo/index.html) or like [this.](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/drop-down-menu/)

How can i make to apply jquery and css on a asp.net menu?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible to use [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) jquery menu on a asp menu but i'm not sure it is really easy..
It will be a "cute" menu..

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Mega DropDown Menus`](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/)